# Is my nearby neighbor's foundation excavation a concern for my home?

Tags: walls, basement, foundation, excavation

Hope someone can answer my Question. I live in Milwaukee WI.My neighbor just informed me she will have to have her basement excavated. The side of her house is 14 feet away from the side of my house. I have a bi-level home. On the side of my home is a finished family room and bedroom. Should I be worried about heavy machinery doing damage to the foundation to my home that could cause problems in the future. Thank You in advance of your answers.

Comment: Yes I lost a valuable clock due to building next door

Answer (score 3):

This is a common situation and is extremely unlikely to cause significant damage to your house. The biggest risks are (a) that someone is exceptionally sloppy and damages your  services (water/sewer/gas/electric) while digging to install the new services, and (B) vibration might provoke a bit of minor settling and a crack or two in your  plaster.

Disasters aren't impossible, but also aren't worth worrying about until they occur, unless there is something very, very odd about your situation. And if a disaster should occur, the builder's insurance should cover it, if they are at all legitimate.

Comment: Also, I'd remove any heavy or valuable items from your walls (throughout the house). Sustained vibration can make for some unpleasant surprises.